# Quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class - Quartz is not executing as expected

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

This is my `Job` which needs to be executed every one minute, this has the dependency on `logger`

```
public class RefreshJob :IJob
{
    public RefreshJob(IContainerFactory containerFactory)
    {
        _logger = containerFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();          
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
         return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _logger.Information("Executing sample job");
                _logger.Information($"Name: {context.JobDetail.Key.Name}");
                _logger.Information($"Description: '{context.JobDetail.Description}'");
                _logger.Information($"Fire time utc: {context.FireTimeUtc:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz}");
            });
    }
}
```

Here is my `dependency injection`

```
   var containerFactory = new ContainerFactory();//class with GetInstance method.
  _builder.Register(c => new RefreshJob(containerFactory)).SingleInstance();
```

This is how I get the `scheduler` reference

```
static async Task<IScheduler> GetScheduler()
{
    var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    return await factory.GetScheduler();
}
```

and I use it in `start` method of my `windows service`

```
public void Start()
{
    Task<IScheduler> scheduler = GetScheduler();
    scheduler.Wait();
    _jobScheduler = scheduler.Result;
    _jobScheduler.Start();

    //Trigger
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<RefreshCacheJob>().Build();
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("RefreshJob", "GroupName")
        .StartAt(DateTime.Now)
        .WithPriority(1)
        .Build();
    _jobScheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

But nothing happens. By the way, I am using `Quartz` scheduler inside `windows service`

**Updated the error**

> Quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class 'Scheduler.RefreshJob' ---> System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor
>   Parameter name: RefreshJob

Comment: On the first sight it looks good. It is possible that some exceptions are thrown and you don't see them. Did you tried some logging or added a [ISchedulerListener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/scheduler-listeners.html) to see if there some exceptions?

Comment: it works for seconds -> .WithCronSchedule("* * * * * ? *")  but not working for any other cron expressions like     .WithCronSchedule("4 * 0 ? * * *")

Comment: @Rabban  added  ISchedulerListener  and it helped to find the cause. seems like dependency injection is issue.

Answer (score 5):

If there's a need to inject a service into the job, follow [this guide](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html#di-aware-job-factories) as @foips commented. Basically you need the following line in your DI container:

```cs
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    ...
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    ...
}
```

Comment: But this is deprecated!

Answer (score 2):

So Setting UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory  works

but the logs still show that error despite clearly injecting the services
into the job.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz need an object to call the executed function, please create an empty constructor to instantiate an object Quartz can use.

[as stated in this documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.7/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03.html)

> One of the ramifications of this behavior is the fact that jobs must have a no-argument constructor (when using the default JobFactory implementation).

Comment: But what if I need to inject a service (UserService, for example) into my Job?

Comment: I know you've probably solved this by now, but you just need to set [UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html#di-aware-job-factories).